# How to call API in terminated/Killed mode in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried to call api in app terminated condition.

My requirement is send location(lat-long) through api call. I am able to send location in foreground and background mode but not in app terminated mode like user killed the app.

I know Apple wont allow this as i found many answer in this topic. But my question is there are some apps who can do this. Like Life360. This app can send location if the app killed mode.

I saw my family member in the map location though his app is not running.

Answer (score 0):

Keep **BackgroundModes** On for Location Updates via XCode settings.

- Then use combination of `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` and `regionMonitoring`.
- Create a region when your app is going in background mode / being terminated.
- In the didExitRegion , start updating location.
- Whenever there are significant location changes, you app will receive updates via delegate methods
- When your app is in terminated mode and app receives location updates, it will be received in `didFinishLaunching` method's launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location]

Comment: can you guide me step by step? I know it seems weird but i am so much confused. Background location fetch is on right now.

Comment: @Raj_Ogma : I understand you are confused, but no one here will guide you step by step with the solution. Instead, can just try to go one step at a time with above solution, and you will be pretty close to the solution.

Comment: Thank you Shantunu. I have two questions: #1- If i switch on startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges then didUpdateLocations delegate will be called? and #2 - can you elaborate your point number 5

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not preferable but you could use `NotificationCenter` by adding an observer or you could use `UserNotifications` and schedule you'r request for specific delivery time.

Comment: Can you guide me with some code? It will help me. I am new in this section.

Comment: You can do something like 
`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.applicationSetup), name: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification, object: nil)`
and on the function **applicationSetup** you can do what ever you want

Comment: i want this as repeat job. it seems it will call once.

Comment: Then you will have to use `UserNotifications` postpone a local notification with turning repetition on

Comment: @Raj_Ogma Take a quick look at the following article, to know how to use local notifications with Swift.
https://medium.com/quick-code/local-notifications-with-swift-4-b32e7ad93c2

Comment: Local notification can be fired only once and cannot be coded as repeat job. as it will crash on this line. You can try and let me know. :(